# Gouraud-shaded triangle with Cairo

Tags: c, cairo

I am trying to get a Gouraud shaded triangle with Cairo using the method explained [here](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-pattern-t.html#cairo-pattern-create-mesh).

I have the following code:

```
cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 240);
cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

cairo_pattern_t * pattern = cairo_pattern_create_mesh();
cairo_mesh_pattern_begin_patch (pattern);
cairo_mesh_pattern_move_to (pattern, 100, 100);
cairo_mesh_pattern_line_to (pattern, 130, 130);
cairo_mesh_pattern_line_to (pattern, 130,  70);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 0, 1, 0, 0);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 1, 0, 1, 0);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 2, 0, 0, 1);
cairo_mesh_pattern_end_patch(pattern);
cairo_set_source(cr, pattern);
cairo_fill(cr);

cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface,"test.png");
```

However the test.png is just black.

Comment: Does it work when you draw it in screen?

Comment: @Jongware: What do you mean by that? I only have a surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cairo_mesh_pattern_line_to()` does not create geometry where actual drawing will happen. It only specifies where the pattern will happen. Thus, to actually see something, you have to specify geometry with e.g. `cairo_line_to()`.

So this should work:

```
cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 240);
cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

cairo_pattern_t * pattern = cairo_pattern_create_mesh();
cairo_mesh_pattern_begin_patch (pattern);
cairo_mesh_pattern_move_to (pattern, 100, 100);
cairo_mesh_pattern_line_to (pattern, 130, 130);
cairo_mesh_pattern_line_to (pattern, 130,  70);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 0, 1, 0, 0);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 1, 0, 1, 0);
cairo_mesh_pattern_set_corner_color_rgb(pattern, 2, 0, 0, 1);
cairo_mesh_pattern_end_patch(pattern);
cairo_set_source(cr, pattern);
cairo_move_to(cr, 100, 100);
cairo_line_to(cr, 130, 130);
cairo_line_to(cr, 130, 70);
cairo_fill(cr);

cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface,"test.png");
```

Comment: Alternatively, just calling cairo_paint(cr); instead of cairo_fill(cr) doesn't need a path.